# Adding label to a text box (programmatically)

Tags: javascript, textbox, dojo, label

How do I add a label to a text box (programmatically) :

```
el = new dijit.form.TextBox({label: '...' });
form.containerNode.appendChild(el.domNode);
```

this does not seem to work (dojo 1.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen any example where the dijit.form.TextBox uses the lable property to actually display a label next to the TextBox.  The label is always a seperate label element or textnode.

I believe the TextBox only has this property because it inherits it from dijit._Widget (according to the [API docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/form/TextBox)).

To add a label programmaticaly, just append a seperate textnode or label element to the form's domNode:

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");

function buildForm() {
    var form = new dijit.form.Form({
    }, dojo.doc.createElement('div'));

    var textBox = new dijit.form.TextBox({
        name: 'text'
    }, dojo.doc.createElement('input'));

    document.body.appendChild(form.domNode);
    form.domNode.appendChild(dojo.doc.createTextNode("My Label "));
    form.domNode.appendChild(textBox.domNode);
}

dojo.addOnLoad(buildForm);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbumpusbarnett/F2qAN/) is a full example on jsfiddle.

Comment: `_Widget`'s label property is actually coming from a dojo.extend call in `dojox/layout/TableContainer`. I asked this same question on the dojo mailing list http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/ValidationTextBox-label-property-td3287477.html. Note that even with this property, it won't be displayed on the page anywhere automatically.

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo Thanks for the added insight.  I looked in the source yesterday and couldn't actually find the label property defined anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

Dojo provides dojox.layout.TableContainer for automatically pairing labels with controls:

```
var layout = new dojox.layout.TableContainer({
    showLabels: true,
    orientation: "horiz"
});

var textBox = new dijit.form.TextBox({
    name: 'text',
    title: 'My Label'
});

layout.addChild(textBox);
layout.placeAt(form.containerNode);
layout.startup();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87DMk/6/) (thanks for the template, @jumpnett)

Comment: This is awesome! However, I don't think you need the startup call at the end anymore. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
yourPlaceholder.domNode.appendChild(dojo.doc.createTextNode("Label Text"));
yourPlaceholder.addChild(yourTextBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it using following snippet :

```
dojo.place('<label for="field" > Label Name </label>',dojo.byId('TextField_Id'),'before');
```